# Assign IMAP folders in Evolution

Tags: email, ubuntu-10.04, imap, evolution

I switched to Ubuntu 10.04, which comes with the Evolution e-mail client. I've grown quite fond of this client but get irritated by one thing. I can't assign IMAP folders to Sent, Junk and Trash! I've got these on my server, but I've got local duplicates. There seems to be no way to make Evolution use the folders on my server. Or is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Sent (and Drafts) folder in the settings for your IMAP account.

Junk and Trash are virtual folders (and in the case of "Trash" that's more or less how IMAP is intended to work anyway: it marks mails as deleted, but doesn't really move them).
AFAIK there is no way to change this in Evolution (currently).

Comment: Fould it! I'll see if I can file a feature request somewhere!

Comment: There already is a feature request in their bugtracker for this, but the developers seem (or seemed?) to favour "doing it right" in the spirit of the IMAP standard specification.  Still, feel free to request this feature; if enough people do that (in a polite way, of course) they might one day accept a patch for it...

Answer (score 0):

You can assign default folders for Sent, Drafts, Trash, and Junk in my version of Gnome e-mail client Evolution (3.10.4).

In the *Account editor* under '**Defaults**' you can assign

- '**Special Folders**' for Sent and Drafts as well as
- '**Use a real Folder for Trash**' for Trash and Junk.